# jquery ajax api post method error with nodejs and express server ... 405: unable to load resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am trying to login a new user and post that instance to SQL using express. On the front end I am getting a server 405 error with my jquery ajax post request.

jquery
the front end request to the backend
i am getting 405 server error

```
  $("#form").on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var user = {
        email: $('loginemail').val(),
        password: $('loginpassword').val()
      };
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/signup",
        data: user
      }).then(function(res){
        if(res.user){
          console.log("boom");
          window.location.href = "./profile-page/index.html";
        }
      });
```

express router
the controller file routed to the /signup post method
using express and sequelize

```
create : function(req,res){
          User.create(req.body).then(function(result,error){
            if(error){
              console.log(error);
              res.send(error);
            }else{
              res.send("./public/profile-page/index.html");
            }
          });
      }
```

this is the html section of the code

```
    <form id="form" >
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <label><b>Email</b></label>
    <input id="loginemail" type="text" placeholder="Enter   
Email"name="email" required>   
    <br>

    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input id="loginpassword" type="password" placeholder="Enter 
Password" name="password" required>
    <br>
```